# Replacing a character in a stringin Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I would like to replace a character in a string like so, WITHOUT using the string function or anything like string.replace.

```
 >>> replace ("banana", "a", "e")
'benene'
```

So for the example, I want to replace character "a" with "e" in the string "banana"

Comment: I suggest using `string.replace`. Or did you mean "_without_ using the string function or anything like string.replace"? In any case, show us the code you've written so far.

Comment: yes how could i do it WITHOUT string.replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single-character replacements are best left to [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
try:
    # Python 2
    from string import maketrans
except ImportError:
    # Python 3
    maketrans = str.maketrans


def replace(original, char, replacement):
    map = maketrans(char, replacement)
    return original.translate(map)
```

`str.translate()` is by far the fastest option for per-character replacement mapping.

Demo:

```
>>> replace("banana", "a", "e")
'benene'
```

This supports mapping multiple characters, just make sure that both the `char` and `replacement` arguments are of equal length:

```
>>> replace("banana", "na", "so")
'bososo'
>>> replace("notabene", "na", "so")
'sotobese'
```

Comment: It works with multiple characters as well if you want ... (+1 this is the right if not necessarily obvious solution imho)

Answer (score 5):

you are not really far :)

```
"banana".replace("a", "e")
```

Unless you meant, **whithout** using the str.replace function :) in which case here's the algorithm

```
def replace(str, old_char, new_char):
    return ''.join([c if c != old_char else new_char for c in str])
```

Comment: how could i do this without .replace?

Comment: @SamyArous `str.join` actually works faster with a list comp than a gen comp, but yuck you're shadowing `str()` in that function!

Comment: i did edit my question, now we haven't learned about .join so I'm not completely sure how it works.

Comment: @AdamSmith yes, I have to get rid of this bad habit :)

Comment: @SamyArous I'm working on chucking it as well. Generators are faster for darn near everything else, just not `str.join` :D

Comment: @user3490645 the join function he (and I) are using is `str.join`, which joins each element from a sequence together with the string you're calling it on. `", ".join(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'])` will return `"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9"`

Comment: @AdamSmith ... generators are only faster for somethings ... mainly they are to preserve ram by not keeping the whole thing in memory at once  ... most of the time when they are used instead of a list they are slower for the equivelent list (marginally, but meh)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Most of my uses for generators can shortcircuit, which make them a good deal faster than creating a whole list just to toss it after I find the item I'm looking for in element 3 :)

Answer (score 2):

If for whatever reason you need to avoid using `str.replace` (YUCK I hate artificial requirements) you can wrap it up in a list comprehension.

```
NEW_CHAR = 'e'
OLD_CHAR = 'a'

''.join([NEW_CHAR if c == OLD_CHAR else c for c in "banana"])
```

Comment: while you can certainly use a generator, its actually faster to use a list if you dont need to use a generator for space reasons ... (+1)

Comment: I was originally responding to @SamyArous's now deleted comment ... yes you are using a list :P (I gave you +1 also :P)